# Find Control Name from non-UI thread

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I found a nice Find Name code snippet that I'm using in a WPF solution:

```
public static T FindVisualChildByName<T>(DependencyObject parent, string name) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            string controlName = child.GetValue(Control.NameProperty) as string;
            if (controlName == name)
            {
                return child as T;
            }
            else
            {
                T result = FindVisualChildByName<T>(child, name);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But this only works if I am on the UI thread.

I have another thread that is playing an audio file with an end sync. I want to use the code above to set a dep property on the ui thread, but I keep getting a cross-thread error.

Even trying a simple:

```
SoundFXPad selectedSoundFXPad = (SoundFXPad)m_parent.FindName("panelC" + numbervar);
```

Gives me the same error

All the other thread-safe WPF Dispatcher-Invoke codes I have seen assume you already know the name of the control. Is there a way to use the either code above in a thread-safe way to affect a UI control from another thread where the name needs to be "found"?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's generally one UI thread per application (generally; you can create multiple, but it's not common). So you don't need the control name to find the dispatcher - try this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(
    delegate {
         // Put code that needs to run on the UI thread here
    }));
```

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick! Only had to add an extra right parenthesis on the end and I now have joy! Thanks for the quick response!